# Thingspeak API security

Tags: security, http

I'm looking at thingspeak which is very interesting. I signed up, created a channel and updated it. But the procedure to do this seems rather simple. One only has to post to the update URI with a key value like this:

```
curl --data "key=bla&field1=1000" http://api.thingspeak.com/update
```

This seems rather insecure for me. One can use `https` of course. But does using TLS make it very secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each request you use `key=bla`, `bla` being your API key. A lot of web APIs use an API key, which the application should keep secure.

As long as no one in between the machine making the request and the API server can intercept network packets, you're safe. Of course you can't guarantee that, so no, it's not secure.

As long as you can prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, TLS will encrypt all HTTP data, including your API key, making it secure against eavesdropping.